# How to set the href of a link with no class or id?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The title tells all; I am trying to change a link with no class or id.

For example, let's say I have a basic website the code of which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="randomdiv">
            <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
        </div>
        <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to change the google.com link to stackoverflow.com. As you can see, the link has no id or class, but the link's parent div `randomdiv` has an id. Also, there are other links on the page, so I can't apply the changes to all links.

I've tried:

```
var d = document.getElementById("randomdiv");
d > a.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

as a random guess. But that didn't work.

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `d > a` is a strange syntax. Learn about `querySelector`

Comment: I tried it as a guess. I asked so I could know the actual syntax.

Comment: Try something like `document.getElementById("randomdiv").getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href='http://stackoverflow.com';`

Comment: Will it always be the only `<a>` element in a parent element with that `id`? Or will it always be a link to 'google.com' that you want to change to 'stackoverflow.com'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select the anchor

```
document.querySelector("#randomdiv a").href = "http://www.example.com";
```

Comment: +1 I need to get into the habit of using `querySelector()` rather than going to the long way around things.

Comment: For Some reason it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of null`

Comment: Well are you trying to find the element before it is rendered to the page?

Comment: @epascarello Oh yeah, probably. (Oops.) EDIT: Yes I am. Thanks. Put it as an answer and I'll happily mark it right.

Answer (score 1):

WRT http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

You can always search an element from an element.

```
var d = document.getElementById("randomdiv");
d. getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```